# Como ejecutar una función cuando la pagina no se recarga

Tags: javascript, ajax

tengo la siguiente funcion para agregar unos textos a un div.

ya que la pag no se recarga entonces para que la funcion se ejecute hay que recargarla, hay una forma de hacerlo sin tener que recargar la pagina?

como se ve en la funcion intente ponerle un tiempo para que se ejecute pero no me funciona.

aclaro que el comportamiento de la pagina que no se recarga al navegar es funcionamiento por defecto del sitio.

```
window.onload = function () {
  function text() {
      var category = document.querySelector('.link--1').textContent;
      if (category == "Electro"){
        console.log("Precio con iva");
        document.querySelector(".listPrecio").prepend("Precio1");
        document.querySelector(".lista").prepend("Precio2 ");
      }
  }
  setTimeout(text, 3000);
}
```

Comment: Se ejecuta a la carga del documento cierto? Si deseas que se ejecute nuevamente debes llamarla explicitamente desde donde se genere ese texto para los divs

Comment: es que esta desde tag manager, entonces esta que se active al entrar a x pagina, al colocar texto plano si sale, pero en el caso de la funcion ya no se ejecuta

Answer (score 1):

No se si entiendo bien lo que quieres pero a ver si es esto:

```
window.onload = function () {
   setTimeout(() => {
    text("Desde window.onload");
   }, 3000);
  }

  function text(texto) {
      console.log(texto);
  }

  text("fuera de window.onload");
```

la funcion debes colocarla por fuera del window.onload para poder acceder a ella desde cualquier lado, en el ejemplo que te puse obviamente se ejecuta primero la que esta por fuera del onload por la cuestion del settimeout